# France visa refusal

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas

Justification for the purpose and conditions of intended stay was not provided. I was been refused on this basis and I was given appeal in French language to CRRV BP 83699 44036 Nantes CEDEX1 France.  How would I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: What information did you provide regarding the purpose and conditions of your intended stay, and what justification did you provide?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that official decisions in Europe contain information where and how to appeal the decision. This information is not a **suggestion** that you should appeal, it is just there for legal reasons. A new application with better plans and circumstances is probably your best option. You must convince the French officials that you are a **genuine** tourist and that you will leave again after visiting France.

- Make a detailed plan for your trip and calculate how much it costs. Don't forget the "little" things like a cup of coffee or an ice cream, those costs add up.
- Compare that to your monthly income after your living expenses at home.

The whole picture must look reasonable to the visa official.